# Какие плагины Вы используете при создании сайтов и блогов на WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Добрый вечер. Какие плагины Вы используете при создании сайтов и блогов на WordPress? Поделитесь, пожалуйста, списком плагинов, если имеется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Auto_more

> Автоматическая вставка `<!--more-->` Если у поста заполнено поле "цитата" (excerpt),
> будет выведено оно.

- Bibs Feed Cat Widget

Добавляет облако меток в сайдбар.

- Disqus Comment System

Заменяет стандартные комментарии WordPress комментариями [Disqus](http://disqus.com/).

- FireStats

Мощная система статистики для блога. Есть некоммерческая и PRO версии. Но, как как и всё чересчур навороченное, жрёт до фига ресурсов, так что я её у себя отключил. Если сайт достаточно большой и на мощном сервере -- попробуйте, иначе не стоит.

- Google XML Sitemaps

Генерирует карту сайта, для поисковиков.

- LiveJournal Crossposter

Автоматически репостит записи из блога в ЖЖ.

- MaxSite Russian Date

> Русские даты.

- NSx Referers

Показывает поисковые запросы, по которым чаще всего находят блог.

- Russify Comments Number

> Нормальное отображение окончания слова "комментарий" - то есть, "2
> комментария", "5 комментариев" и так далее.

- RusToLat

> Транслитерация русских символов URL в английские.

- Subscribe2

Подписка на новые посты по email. Зарегистрированные пользователи могут настроить подписку на отдельные категории.

- wL Email Encrypter

Защищает адреса электронной почты от считывания ботами.

- wp-cache

Думаю, из названия всё понятно.

- `wp_stem_ru`

> Улучшение поиска за счет обработки поискового запроса стеммером Портера.

- Yet Another Related Posts Plugin

Вывод похожих постов.

Answer (score 0):

Плагины служат для расширения функционала, которого нет из коробки, а никак не для того "чтобы были". Функционала, который нужен КОНКРЕТНОМУ сайту. 
Ставить плагины не понимая зачем они (и тем более не настраивая их) - зло.

Какие задачи нужно решить - о том и спрашивай.